# REGEX: how to capture terminal flags and arguments?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, ecmascript-6, capturing-group

I'm trying to do some custom terminal flags and arguments, hoping to learn something new, and I feel something is missing, here is what I tried:

```regex
/(?<flag>-{0,2}[., a-z0-9_-]*)(?<=\s*)(?<![-])(?<arguments>[\[\<]\S+)?/gim
```

Note: it's an ES6 regex.

here are the examples to be tested on:

```
-d, --devices <command> [ios-type...]
-n --no-run
-m, --mobile
-a, --all
-p, --platforms
--os <os-type>
```

I'm trying to capture all hyphen starting params as a `<flag>` group in one match.

While capturing each of the argument in a separate `<arguments>` group as different matches.

if you would try it in https://regex101.com/ you will notice extra spaces and null matches in both `<flag>` and `<arguments>` in which I didn't know how to get rid of.

here are the results:

```
-d, --devices <command>
-d, --devices 
<command>
 [ios-type...]
 
[ios-type...]


-n --no-run
-n --no-run


-m
-m


 --mobile
 --mobile


-a, --all
-a, --all


-p, --platforms
-p, --platforms


--os <os-type>
--os 
<os-type>
```

if you have any thoughts please let me know.

Comment: I think you should post your results here instead of asking us to set your problem up on some other site.

Comment: That's a good Idea, thanks for the suggestion. 

Comment: Json is too long, csv is missy, Plain text right?

Comment: why don't you use a command line argument parser?

Comment: you mean in nodejs?

Comment: I feel like I missed that part, let me have a look at it

Comment: I'm not entirely sure it would fit my needs, it may, but it will be a little long, hence, I'm using `commander` but I do have a little of extra custom needs.

Comment: Can you just clarify, you want to capture both the single `-` flag and the double `--` flag from the same line in the same group?

Comment: yes, so these are in one capture: `-d, --delete` or `-d --delete`, I may have one flag or two as previous and `--os`